# How can i force angular.js NOT to remove a 0-value from the model?

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object containing some properties, whose values can become 0. They are bound to a set of radio buttons (the first ones value is 0). The problem is now, that if i choose the first radio button, the property will be removed by angular.js by default. But i want to keep it with a zero as value.

I also need a way to preselect the first radio button if the value of the bound property is 0/the property doesn't exist. The checked="checked" attribute doesn't work for any reason it the bound value is 0/doesn't exist.

Is there a way to achieve it? Thank you.

The radio buttons:

```
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="0" ng-model="item.type" 
           ng-init="item.type=0" ng-checked="true"/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="1" ng-model="item.type"/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="2" ng-model="item.type"/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="3" ng-model="item.type"/>
```

The controller:

```
    $scope.item = {
            type: 0
    };
```

Comment: Solved the preselection using ng-init="0" and ng-checked="true" for a 0-Value. But i still don't know how to keep the property.

Comment: Show us your code. Without it, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Here is it. The ng-init/ng-checked solution seems not to work inside ng-repeat. :/

Comment: The `ngChecked` directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior. For more information, see [AngularJS `ngChecked` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).